# Pandas to GBQ method returning GenericGBQException: Reason 404 POST

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

This error just started to pop up in our pipelines.
I'm moving a dataframe that's about 1.5mil rows using the pandas.to_gbq method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
output.to_gbq('table_name', 
'project-id',
chunksize=50000, 
private_key='ga_auth.json',
if_exists='replace'
)
```

Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\rfm_bigquery.py", line 175, in <module>
    send_rfm_to_gbq()
  File ".\rfm_bigquery.py", line 152, in send_rfm_to_gbq
    if_exists='replace',
  File "C:\Users\yyu\Desktop\env\rfm_bigquery\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1187, in to_gbq
    table_schema=table_schema)
  File "C:\Users\yyu\Desktop\env\rfm_bigquery\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 119, in to_gbq
    table_schema=table_schema)
  File "C:\Users\yyu\Desktop\env\rfm_bigquery\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 1036, in to_gbq
    progress_bar=progress_bar,
  File "C:\Users\yyu\Desktop\env\rfm_bigquery\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 513, in load_data
    self.process_http_error(ex)
  File "C:\Users\yyu\Desktop\env\rfm_bigquery\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 376, in process_http_error
    raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 404 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/hidden-moon-164616/jobs?uploadType=resumable: Not Found
```

Comment: This just says that your given project-id is not found. Are you setting up auth and stuff properly?

Comment: yeah i actually read from the project earlier in the script and the auth is working.This looks to be some sort of 'resumable' part is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the latest version, I moved back to pandas==0.23.3 and pandas-gbq==0.5.0 and it is finally working ...